# Randomly place a text on some buttons

Tags: java, android

I am trying to move, say a text or number in `setText(Integer.toString())` format randomly on 4 different buttons at each click. I am able to obtain the object form of it, but it is worthless since I can't get that information out of it.

This is my code:

```
public void clickButton(View view){
    
    List mo = new ArrayList();
    mo.add(Button);
    mo.add(Button1);
    mo.add(Button2);
    mo.add(Button3); // these are defined in OnCreate method

    Random rko = new Random();
    int koo = rko.nextInt(mo.size());
    Object a = mo.get(koo);
    
    Log.i("here", String.valueOf(mo.get(koo)));
```

I get this output in the logs up on each click

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{71c6fe0 VFED..C.. ...PH... 697,708-928,933 #7f0c0052 app:id/Button2}
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{71c6fe0 VFED..C.. ...PH... 697,708-928,933 #7f0c0052 app:id/Button3}
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton{71c6fe0 VFED..C.. ...PH... 697,708-928,933 #7f0c0052 app:id/Button}
```

I am new to this. Please help
Thanks.

Comment: I was hoping that somehow I could use the  output of mo.get(koo) which could give me the button and then I can set the text - button.setText()

Answer (score 0):

hi i believe that u should use tags on your buttons p = new Random().nextInt(21);

```
    button.setTag(Integer.toString(alpha));
```

//here alpha is the text that you wanted to put on the button,get the text from button by using appropriate code

```
    cbutton.setTag(Integer.toString(" "));
```

Comment: i used integer but u can use String also

Answer (score 0):

You could try writing `AppCompatButton` instead of `Object` and then you should be able to get the text of a button with `a.getText();` and change the text of a button with `a.setText();`.

Answer (score 0):

@Rushikesh You did not restrict the random generated number within the range of 0-4.
The size of array list of button is 4 so the the **index** must be 0-4 to avoid the **IndexOutOfBoundsException**

```
List mo = new ArrayList();
    mo.add(Button);
    mo.add(Button1);
    mo.add(Button2);
    mo.add(Button3); 

int koo = (int)(Math.random() * (10-(mo.size()+1))); // generated number range will be 0-4
Object a = mo.get(koo);
```